# NSInteger and int giving exceptions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsinteger, sqldatatypes

I'm trying to get data from a database using FMDB but having tried with futility for a while, I can't figure out why this is throwing an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception. The parameter is passed in from an NSInteger, but I can neither log it nor use it in a SELECT statement. The code I have is:

```
-(SQLiteResult*) getClient:(bool)forceRefresh id:(NSString*)id forYear:(NSInteger)year {
    SQLiteResult *res;
    if(!forceRefresh){
        NSMutableArray *hereditaments = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE ID = %@ AND Year = %@", id, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", year]]); // exception
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE ID = %@ AND Year = %@", id, year]]); // also exception
        FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE ID = ? AND Year = %@", year], id]; // also exception
        FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE ID = ? AND Year = ?", id, year]]; // also exception
```

I'm on the verge of just passing it in as a string instead. Is there a safe way I can just use the year in the SQL statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your year variable is of NSInteger type you should use %d format and not %@ in your NSString creation

Comment: Formatting it as %d instead of passing it to the query as a parameter worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`NSInteger` is not an object type. Its just a `typedef` of type `int`. So, you can not use `%@` as the format specifier. You should use `%d`.